# Did Para Support separate column in postgres instead of storing in one json format

Tags: spring-boot, frameworks, para

I store data in postgres but it storing as one single column in JSON in using para in springboot is there any way to store data in seperate column in postgres . Also when I do Para.getDAO.create(obj) its not working but pc.create is working

private final ParaClient pc = new ParaClient(access key , secret key )
pc.create(c)

but
Para.getDAO.create(c) not working

Answer (score 0):

The Para plugin for working with SQL databases works that way and cannot store data in separate columns. Your only option is to write your own DAO plugin (perhaps a fork of the `para-dao-sql` plugin) and make it work for you.

If you are using the Para client in your application, you can only talk to the Para server using an instance of `ParaClient`. You can import the whole `para-server` package and then use `Para.getDAO().create(c)` but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: when I do pc.read(c) it was giving me as a Sysprop object not as a MyClassName object even the type was set as MyClassName in postgres database.

Comment: The custom obejct type has to be declared in its own Java class and Para must read it in order to convert Sysprop to MyClassName. https://paraio.org/docs/#010-userdefined

Comment: yes i added the type field but it didn't read it to MyClassName

Comment: A type field as a string isn't enough. You need a POJO class declared and implemented.

Comment: done with those declaration and  extending of sysprop class still only giving sysprop object.Also when i write my custom dao should I manually need to create a table schema for that in my postgres .

Comment: Please, see the link to the Para docs on how to configure Para to read your custom core classes. When wriying a DAO you need to take care of all database operations including schema creation.

Comment: I was able to override the CRUD operation but the schema creation is done via sqlUtils class which i was unable to override it as it was set to final then how to override those createtable methods. Also while doing custom CRUD i have to call it via customdao.create not pc.create which leads to unable catching or indexing so how to enable pc.create with my customDao

Comment: You have to run your own Para server and load the custom DAO plugin there. You can't modify the existing SQL DAO functions in `SqlUtils`. Not sure why you would want to go through all this complicated setup.

Comment: I want to perform complex query operations like joins, subqueries, group by and it was not possible when data is stored in NoSql fashion (json ) in database.